# What was Jason Bourne actually doing to the elevators?

Tags: plot-explanation, jason-bourne

InJason Bourne (2016), Jason removes an elevator control board and hits something.

[image]

Outside the elevator symbol changes into RED COLOUR "--".

[image]

What was Jason Bourne actually doing to the elevators?

Comment: Activating the emergency stop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the display is green, it indicates whether the elevator goes upwards or downwards, and to which floor the elevator is heading. Bourne switched off these indicators so that the pursuing agents do not know which way he is heading (up or down) and which floor his destination is.

When the indicator works properly (green), it shows if the lift goes up or down:

[image]

It also shows the floor number:

[image]

Switching off those indicators, the agents are missing some vital info regarding the direction and actual positions of the elevators, it creates confusion, and this makes the pursuit harder, Bourne can buy himself some precious time. The agents do not know exactly where he is heading (up or down), to which floor he is heading, where Bourne's elevator currently is, and when one of the agents calls a lift for himself, he also doesn't know exactly where his lift is, how much time it takes until his lift arrives (Bourne swithes off the indicator of not only his own elevator, but that of those surrounding lifts as well, see pic below).:

[image]